# Yoink alternative for Windows

Tags: windows, drag-drop

Is there any program like [Yoink](http://eternalstorms.at/yoink/) for Windows?

Yoink is a program that allows you to store multiple files in a panel to copy or cut and paste them at your directory. To get the file, you need to hold the mouse at the left side of the screen and a panel with comes over and you can drag and drop stored files without copying them. Also, can drag and drop to applications etc. trough that panel that you stored files at there.

[image: Yoink interface. "Take the 'drag' out of drag'n'drop"]

Comment: You can simply copy and paste the folders or files at any place in windows. I think you don't need a separate software for that. Could you be more clear in explaining what you really want?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: Edited With More Information

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to reopen it on this base. Please add as well whether you need gratis software (free as in "free beer" or free as in "free speech"), or if you have a budget.