# Same as yoink for OS X but for Windows

Tags: windows, drag-drop

I have software Yoink on my Mac Os and I like it. However, I want to find same function app on Windows 10. Is there anything like that?
There is same topic but no reply inside.
[Yoink alternative for Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27752/yoink-alternative-for-windows)

Comment: Please [edit] your question according to [this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software)

Comment: It would have helped if you told us what Yoink does. Moist of us probably have access to Window's PCs and know a lot of apps. Not so many of us have a Mac, so we are unlikely to know what Yoink does.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing which comes in my mind is [Fences](https://www.stardock.com/products/fences/)

It allows you to pin folder to your desktop. You could create one to store files you want to copy. Definitely not the same but eventually it helps you.

Directly navigation to a destination folder is way easier in windows (personal opinion). You can just drag & drop from one program to the other, you can also simply swap the active folder with the keyboard or jumping on the desktop.

Comment: Thanks. I wish it is not very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Try Droppoint
https://github.com/GameGodS3/DropPoint

Its open source cross platform alternative to Dropover.
Works perfectly on my windows!!